# Can not open PDF document when an order is completed

Tags: invoice, pdf

I am receiving an error with the PDF document when an order is completed and I select “Print Invoice” from the drop down menu. When the PDF has been generated and l go to open it on my computer l get the following error:

“there was an error opening this document. the file is damaged and could not be repaired”

Has any had this issue and if so how can l fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have an error in your output like an exception or similar.

To find a solution first look in your error logs if something bad happens.

Next is to open the pdf inside a text editor and look if you find a php error message or other output which belongs on a website, not inside a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem,

and i found this on my log:

```
[2019-08-19 20:27:23] main.INFO: Add of item with id WeltPixel_GoogleTagManager::GoogleTagManager was processed [] []
[2019-08-19 20:27:23] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice\View\Interceptor" [] []
[2019-08-19 20:27:23] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice\View\Interceptor" [] []
[2019-08-19 20:27:23] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice\View\Interceptor" [] []
[2019-08-19 20:27:23] main.DEBUG: Não há tal entidade com customerId =  [] []
[2019-08-19 20:27:29] main.DEBUG: Não há tal entidade com customerId =  [] []
[2019-08-19 20:27:30] main.DEBUG: Não há tal entidade com customerId =  [] []
[2019-08-19 20:27:30] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice\View\Interceptor" [] []
[2019-08-19 20:27:30] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice\View\Interceptor" [] []
[2019-08-19 20:27:33] main.DEBUG: Não há tal entidade com customerId =  [] []
[2019-08-19 20:27:36] main.DEBUG: Não há tal entidade com customerId =  [] []
[2019-08-19 20:27:42] main.DEBUG: Não há tal entidade com customerId =  [] []
[2019-08-19 20:27:53] main.DEBUG: Não há tal entidade com customerId =  [] []
[2019-08-19 20:28:01] main.DEBUG: Não há tal entidade com customerId =  [] []
[2019-08-19 21:19:52] main.DEBUG: URI '/'' cannot be accessed with HEAD method (Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index) [] []
[2019-08-19 21:19:52] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor" [] []
```